# How to temporarily disable deleting and editing?

Tags: edit

I sometimes use vim for brainstorming and writing first drafts and would like to be able to temporarily disable the ability to delete or edit what I write down. Is there anyway to do this natively in vim?

Comment: "Disable the ability to delete or edit what your write"? You mean that you want Vim to behave as if you only had Insert mode without Backspace key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `:set nomodifiable` which disables any changes which you will try to do in some buffer. Look here, `:h modifiable`.

Comment: And `:set modifiable!` toggles between the two values; useful for key mappings: `nnoremap <Leader>n :set modifiable!<CR>:set modifiable?<CR>` (that second :set is to show the setting after pressing the key).